# Looking up strings of two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames

a) I have a Dataframe with 3 strings

```
Product = {'P': ['Tee','Lee', 'Nee']}
Product = DataFrame(Product, columns=['P'])
```

b) I have a large Dataframe with the column 'Verleihgruppe' of the dataframe 'dfd' containing these 3 strings of Products among many others

Task: I want to replace all the Strings of 'Product' in the second dataframe dfd in the column 'Verleihgruppe' with the string 'Rental'. Subsequently, I want to copy these 'Rental' strings in the same row of a different column of the dataframe dfd.

Comment: This looks like a good use of [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), but without a sample input and output it's difficult to say for certain how to help